# TypeError: unorderable types: NoneType() >= str()

Tags: cython, mingw32

I am new to cython and I am trying to compile the following code

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
setup(
    ext_modules=cythonize('helloworld.pyx'),
    )
```

im using mingw32 compiler for this purpose using the command

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace --compiler=mingw32
```

this however generates the error

```
running build_ext
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 4, in <module>
    ext_modules=cythonize('helloworld.pyx'),
  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 308, in run
    force=self.force)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\ccompiler.py", line 1031, in new_compiler
    return klass(None, dry_run, force)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\cygwinccompiler.py", line 282, in __init__
    CygwinCCompiler.__init__ (self, verbose, dry_run, force)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\cygwinccompiler.py", line 126, in __init__
    if self.ld_version >= "2.10.90":
TypeError: unorderable types: NoneType() >= str()
```

I am stuck at this part from a really long time .I am using python3.4 in a windows10 system.Thank you in advance